# Optimising a custom tree data structure

Tags: c++, tree

I have the following 'custom' tree data structure.  This concept was to be thought of as, if given ("abb", 20) and ("abc", 30), then

> ```
> Tree['a']['b']['b'] == 20
> ```

> ```
> Tree['a']['b']['c'] == 30
> ```

Or

> ```
> a
>  \
>   b
>  / \
> b   c
> ```

With b == 30, and c == 20.

Therefore taking up very limited space, and a very fast search.
However, as depth increases, the number of bytes for a fully explored tree was exponential. In the above case, 4 * 256 bytes were required for valid indexing to occur.  This was not good.

It now works in the following way; for each branch, compare its value against the n character; i.e. introducing a worst case O(256) character comparison for each depth. This is not ideal, and what I want to attempt to change.

---

The other question was (and still is), what is it? I couldn't quite classify it as anything but a Tree; nor relate it to any `std::` containers for comparison. It is very good at what it does though, out-performing a `std::map` with small strings and very large strings (sizes ~20, ~500 respectively); past 600, the data structure begins to get too heavy.

Obviously, this code is a bit sketchy in how it handles the templates at the moment.  A number of things could go wrong, but my interest (other than classification) is on improving this data structure.

```
template <class K, class V>
class Tree {
    unsigned int depth;
    Tree* parent;

    std::vector<Tree> branches;
public:
    K key;
    V val;

    int n_trees;
    Tree(K key = 0, int depth = 0, Tree* parent = 0) : depth(depth), parent(parent), key(key) {
        val = 0;
        n_trees = 0;
        inc();
    }

    void inc() {
        if (parent) parent->inc();
        n_trees++;
    }

    void add(const K* search, const unsigned int length, const V value) {
        const int index = search[depth];

        if (length <= depth) {
            val = value;
            return;
        }

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < branches.size(); ++i) {
            if (branches[i].key == index) {
                branches[i].add(search, length, value);
                return;
            }
        }
        branches.push_back(
            Tree(index, depth + 1, this)
        );
        branches.back().add(search, length, value);
    }
    V find(const K* search, const unsigned int length) {
        const int index = search[depth];

        if (length <= depth) {
            return val;
        }

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < branches.size(); ++i) {
            if (branches[i].key == index) {
                return branches[i].find(search,length);
            }
        }
        return 0; // won't work for all types lol
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Why do you have `m_parent`? I don't think there are any reasonable operations on a trie that require a parent pointer in each node, and removing it can reduce the space used a lot.

---

I don't love using a `depth` argument in `add`. I'd use the following instead:

```
void add(const std::string& key, const T& value) {
  return add(key.data(), key.size(), value);
}
void add(const char *key, const T& value) {
  return add(key, std::strlen(key), value);
}
void add(const char* key, std::size_t len, const T& value);  // impl below
```

---

I suggest that you keep the children sorted by `m_key`. Write a comparison functor like so:

```
struct KeyLessThan {
  bool operator()(const PrefixTree& l, const PrefixTree& r) const {
    return l.m_key < r.m_key;
  }
  bool operator()(const PrefixTree& tree, char c) const {
    return l.m_key < c;
  }
};
```

Now you can rewrite `add` like this (using the signature above):

```
void PrefixTree::add(const char* key, std::size_t len, const T& value) {
  assert(len >= 0);
  if (len == 0) {
    m_value = value;
    return;
  }
  auto it = std::lower_bound(begin(m_branches), end(m_branches),
                             *key, KeyLessThan());
  if (it == end || it->m_key != *key) {
    it = m_branches.emplace(it, *key);
  }
  it->add(key + 1, len - 1, value);
}
```

The size of `m_branches` is bounded to be quite small (256 elements in theory; in practice if you're doing English words only it'll be 26 or 52 at the root and much smaller in interior nodes), so this should be quite fast, and it'll make `find` faster.

---

Speaking of `m_branches`, `m_children` would be a more usual name for it.

---

It's not really clear that you want `find` to return a `T*`; it's odd to give out handles to internal memory in a data structure like this. I would make the signature one of

```
const T* find(const std::string& key) const
std::pair<bool, const T&> find(const std::string& key) const
```

or

```
std::pair<bool, T> find(const std::string& key) const
```

(if you have access to a C++14 implementation, even better is

```
std::optional<T> find(const std::string& key) const
```

Whichever you choose, use the same overloads as with `add` for `const char *`, etc.

---

It is very weird to me to see an `#include` that's not at the top of the file, and to see `printf`s in the middle of a C++ file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!
The random include was because these code snippets were plastered together for the example. The `printf`s were just debugging.

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions:

You are using a vector for your branches but you are using an index loop to iterate through the vector.
I'd consider using the vector iterator.
This will make your code a bit clearer and versatile (if you decide to change the container type for example). Will also get rid of the double branches[i] access in each loop.

Should the n_trees be public? You could write a get function but I'm guessing the client code shouldn't be allowed to change that.

For the return value at the end, if you cast it to V, I think that might work for all types, although I'm not sure about that.